# Communication between Flash and Java/C# server based app

Tags: c#, java, flash, actionscript-3

For example, Flash records voice and sends it to the server where Java or C# apps can proccess it and return back some data (or write it to db).
How this communication possible, which protocols sould be used and etc.

Comment: the flash client is probably connecting with http to a servlet

Comment: Why did you edit out your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just have a server socket in java or C/C++/C# whatever, use the flash Socket class to connect to the open socket on the server and do your transactions through that socket.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/Socket.html

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7c60.html#WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7c63

Sample code here: (Too long to paste in an answer)

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/Socket.html#includeExamplesSummary

Answer (score 1):

Besides the raw socket communication, the general formats for communication with Flash to server are [AMF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Action_Message_Format) and [RTMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_Time_Messaging_Protocol)